# why my value only return 1 letter?

Tags: php

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Player name"/>

    <select id="t-size" name="t-size">
        <option value="S">S</option>
        <option value="M">M</option>
        <option value="L">L</option>
        <option value="XL">XL</option>
        <option value="XXL">XXL</option>
        <option value="XXXL">XXXL</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

then it submit and post to `process.php`

```
if(isset($_POST) == true && empty($_POST) == false) {
    $BX_NAME = $_POST['name'];  
    $BX_size=$_POST['t-size'];

    foreach($BX_NAME as $a => $b) { 
        echo $BX_NAME[$a];
        echo $BX_size[$a];
    }
}
```

I have two problem here,

1. I get the data with no break, so lets say `name=chico size=xxl` and I will get `"chicox"` I need to break them off,
2. My size value, why I only get the first letter? it should be `xxl` not `x`.

Comment: `<select id="t-size" name="t-size[]">` ?

Comment: `echo $BX_NAME[$a] . " " . $BX_size`

Comment: oh sorry i was the same i copy from the wrong one. i edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue, you must have break on process.php as:

```
foreach($BX_NAME as $a => $b){ 
    echo "name = ".$BX_NAME[$a]."<br />";
    echo "size = ".$BX_size[$a]."<br />";
}
```

For the second, you must add [] to the size name to PHP can get it as an array. You can change in HTML:

```
<select id="t-size" name="t-size">
```

to

```
<select id="t-size" name="t-size[]">
```

Answer (score 1):

we use array(`name="name[]"`) to store data if having multiple inputs with same name. So here you don't want to create it just use `name="name"`.

and in `submit` button define a attribute with `name`

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
```

and in `php`code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $bx_name = $_POST['name'];
    $bx_size = $_POST['t-size'];

    if(empty($bx_name) || empty($bx_size))
    {
        echo 'Input Fields are empty';
    }
    else
    {
        //no need to use foreach loop

        echo 'Player name is '.$bx_name;
        echo '<br/>';
        echo 'T-Shirt Size is '.$bx_size;
    }

}
```